# Google Analytics Reporting Api - PHP: Add user account

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

**What I want to do**

- Let user of my web application share their analytics account with the app.
- Redirect the user to Google authentication  which ask them to approve access
- Redirect the user back to the app.
- Generate a report for the user based on his analytics data and data from the app.
- Next time the user will generate their report I don't want to ask them for the logging again.

**Where the problem is**

I read this [Google developers PHP guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php). However, the sample code connects to first account that is already shared with the app.

I want to see a piece of code that ask user for their credentials and consequently provides access to their account.

On Stack I've already found this answer [Service Applications and Google Analytics API V3: Server-to-server OAuth2 authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863509/service-applications-and-google-analytics-api-v3-server-to-server-oauth2-authen/10089698#10089698). However, mentioned APP_EMAIL is not a particular user's e-mail, but developer.gserviceaccount.com identification for the app created in the console.

Also I found this thread [Google Analytics Core Reporting API Version 3.0 without client login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966554/google-analytics-core-reporting-api-version-3-0-without-client-login). It seems that similar topic is solved there, but the important part of code (from my point of view) is missing there.

Comment: Remember credentials Is not a users login and password.  It is a refresh token that will give you access to their account in the future.   Service accounts will not work for you in this case.   It would be a bad idea.   I have a tutorial series that might help get you started.  http://www.daimto.com/google-development-beginners/   The code in the answer posted by Dimi should work.

Comment: aha that was my problem - i didn't realize that token is used instead of credentials, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure to grab refresh token by settings access type to offline.
Then Create a separate page for reporting.
Separate page should be using account id and refresh token for all reporting, and if it gives you an error on token, you can either refresh it yourself, or send them back to login page.

you only need to ask for credentials once and you get access to all accounts. The php guide only uses the first account, however you can iterate through all of them and get more

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/creds/client_secrets.json');
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_EDIT);
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

// If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
// else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
        // Set the access token on the client.
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        // Create an authorized analytics service object.
        $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
        $accounts=getAccountIds($analytics);
        foreach($accounts as $acc)
        {
         var_dump($acc);
}
}
else {
        $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php';
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```